# retriving date only from database by using servlets and displaying the result in jsp page

Tags: jsp, servlets

how to retriving the date only not date and time from database by using servlets and how to display the result in jsp page

Comment: "date only not date and time" - you're going to have to explain your database schema / column values and more of what you want to achieve.  "by using servlets" - servlets != database.  You can definitely use database related technologies like JDBC / Hibernate / iBatis / etc. *in* a servlet - but this is not really any different than using them in any other context.  "display the result in jsp page" - do you have specific questions about this or need a JSP primer?

Comment: Pulling the value out of the database in teh format you want would be best but how to do that depends on the db.

Answer (score 3):

When you retrieve the date from a date field in the database you are getting both the date and the time as you noticed. This is not a problem. If you want to display only the date then simply configure the display to do so. Assume that you are using JSTL to display:

```
 <fmt:formatDate type="date" value="${the date}" dateStyle="short"/>
```

will display only the date and not the time.

Answer (score 0):

create a servlet that retrieves the date from the database (with a JDBC driver or similar) and sets it as a request parameter (request.setParameter()), then forward the request using the RequestDispatcher to the JSP file.

The jsp file can then access this parameter with request.getParameter().